# How to create excel file with multiple sheets from DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to export DataGridViews data into the Excel file .
I want to make 3 sheet and export data to those .
There is no problem with one workSheet.
But when i want to make more Sheet and click the button, the below Error message appear .

> Debugger:Exception Intercepted: button1_Click, Form2.cs line 34
>   An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occurred.  "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options.
>   Time: 5/20/2020 11:11:53 PM
>   Thread:[17068]

**Here is the Button click event .**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // creating Excel Application  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        // see the excel sheet behind the program  
        app.Visible = true;
        // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.  
        // store its reference to worksheet  
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet"+x+""];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            // changing the name of active sheet  
            worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
            // storing header part in Excel  
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                }
            }
        }

        // save the application  
        workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        // Exit from the application  
        //app.Quit();  
    }
```

**solution :**

replace

> workbook.Sheets.Add();

with

> worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet"+x+""];

and add counter to name of sheet

> worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview"+x+"";

Answer (score 0):

Fund the answer.
just replace

> workbook.Sheets.Add();

with

> worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet"+x+""];

and add counter to name of sheet

> worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview"+x+"";